# Unable to start Firefox on CentOS 6 from iterm2 on Mac

Tags: ssh, firefox, centos, iterm2, timeout

I have installed Firefox and xauth on the CentOS 6.6 server as follows:

```
sudo yum install firefox
sudo yum install xauth
```

On my Mac, I am using iTerm2. 
On my iTerm2 session, I also exported my display as follows:

```
export DISPLAY=192.168.0.3:0.0
```

Then from my iTerm2 session I ssh to this CentOS 6.6 server as follows:

```
ssh -Y server
```

Then in my CentOS 6.6 server I try to start Firefox as follows:

```
firefox&
```

Then, after a long time, I get the connection timed out error as follows:

```
$ firefox&
[1] 56352
$ connect 192.168.0.3 port 6000: Operation timed out
```

Can someone please help me fix this so that I can start Firefox on CentOS 6.6 using from iTerm2 on Mac using ssh?

Comment: Crossposted on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309077/unable-to-start-firefox-on-centos-6-from-iterm2-on-mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to open firefox now. 
**But it is extremely slow** 
Anything I type in URL, it shows getting typed after big lag. 
Same is for any form input values. 
I wanted to use it for automation suite. 
So probably its useless for any practical purpose.

Following steps worked for me:

1) On centOs server:

```
sudo yum install firefox
sudo yum install xauth
```

2) On Mac - installed XQuartz and opened its terminal. 
Basically followed this link https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=280461906

**Did not export DISPLAY this time on xterm on mac.**

3) xhost +

4) ssh into the centos server from the xterm (from quartz) not iterm2:

```
ssh -Y server
```

5) Started firefox in centos from xterm:

```
firefox&
```